# Flutter - how to ask user permission for access storage/messages?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

how to ask for initial permission while installing the flutter app?

1. when a new user installs the app.
2. using local storage to show last used app page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to ask permission for that. You can use `SharedPreferneces` without explicit consent and store there which was the last screen visited.

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences